# Render returned string in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I have been working a lot with Django's template language lately, and it works well in most cases, but recently I've come across a small problem it hasn't been able to solve.
I'm iterating over a bunch of database objects, and building a button in the template from each of them. Something like this:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <button id="{{ item.action.id }}">
        {{ item.action.text }}
    </button>
{% endfor %}
```

This works fine, but my `Action` class is inheritable, and may have a different button structure. Say I wanted to sometimes have a javascript function attached as well. My first though was *well, let's just create a render method in my class*, and then call that in my template.

```
class ScriptAction(Action):

    def render(self):
        return '''
            <button id="{}" onclick={}>
                {}
            </button>'''.format(self.id, self.func, self.text)
```

Because no the template is much more elegant, and doesn't rely on a fixed button structure:

```
{% for item in items %}
    {{ item.action.render|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

And now for my actual problem: **what if this rendered string needs further processing by django?**
Maybe render method returns a string like

```
<button id="action-button-id" onclick="console.log('clicked')">
    {{ item.name }}
</button>
```

Currently, `{{ item.name }}` will not be rendered in the template loop. Is there a way of getting around this?

Perhaps I making this more complicated than it should be, but I've looked through the Django built-in tags and filters, even looked at [writing you own parser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#advanced-custom-template-tags).  But at this point something inside me told me that I was being obsessive. This is actually just a small problem, and would require a fair amount of time, so -

- is this more effort than it is worth?
- is writing complex parsers like this secure?
- is the Django template language even able to do something like this?

If you could hone in on some of these points, I would really appreciate it. This problem is really bugging me.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look into the [simple_tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) option for building a custom template tag, and have the tag:

1. Take the model instance as its argument (plus context!)
2. Ask the model instance for a snippet of template code to use in rendering it
3. Use [the raw template API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context) to render that template snippet
4. Return the result, optionally marked safe if you know it is safe.

Comment: Fantastic! This is a powerful little tool